# How to use the Haxe Swift target?

Tags: swift, haxe

So, I just installed the haxe swift target from https://github.com/ralcr/swift-target and I can't figure out for the life of me how I'm supposed to get it to compile a `.hx` file into a `.swift` file.

I've tried `haxe -main HelloWorld.hx -swift [filename]` as well as `haxe -main HelloWorld.hx -swift [directory]` (and yes, I replaced both [filename] and [directory] with their respective replacements) but neither work. How do I do compile it to a swift file?

Comment: I don't think that that project is actually functional and it has not been updated for a long time. I suggest you open an issue there to question its status.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.